# How to rename multiple files to the same file name and move to multiple folders using R?

Tags: r, directory, filenames, directory-structure

I have around 500 files that all need to be named the same thing but need unique file path names.

So far I have been dropping each of the files manually into separate folders and renaming them, but this takes forever and I have to repeat the process each time I make a change to the original data.

To create the files I used the R code:

```
lapply(names(dfsplit), function(x){
  write.csv(dfsplit[[x]], path = paste(x, ".csv", sep = ""))
})
```

Is there a way at this stage to create individual folders for each of the csv files and rename them e.g. 'name.csv' as they are created? Maybe using dir.create?

Let me know if this needs a clearer explanation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, and perhaps add some sample input data, and the expected output?